# Datatables - send parameter to server side processing

Tags: datatables, server-side

I need to send a parameter to server side processing by the selecting an option in list and the retrieve only the records that match the selection.

1) Javascript: What is the best way to send a parameter?

2) PHP: How can I get the value received and filter the array?

**Html**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="title">Pick Name:</label>
    <select name="iname" class="form-control" onchange="showUser(this.value)" style="width:500px">
        <option value="Fred">Fred</option>
        <option value="Lucy">Lucy</option>
        <option value="Amy">Amy</option>
        <option value="Joe">Joe</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function showUser(str){             
    $('#mytable').DataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "go1.php",           
        "aoColumns": [
                        { mData: 'Name' },
                        { mData: 'Start Date' },
                        { mData: 'End Date' },
                        { mData: 'Notes' }          
                       ]
    });
};
```

**PHP**

```
$data = array(
        array('Name'=>'Lucy', 'Start Date'=>'2017-11-01', 'End Date'=>'2017-11-01', 'Notes'=>'Notes02'),
        array('Name'=>'Amy',  'Start Date'=>'2017-09-01', 'End Date'=>'2017-09-11', 'Notes'=>'Notes03'),
        array('Name'=>'Fred', 'Start Date'=>'2017-02-03', 'End Date'=>'2017-02-04', 'Notes'=>'Notes04'),
        array('Name'=>'Joe',  'Start Date'=>'2017-03-05', 'End Date'=>'2017-03-21', 'Notes'=>'Notes05')
);

$results = array(
    'sEcho'=>'1',
    'iTotalRecords'=>count($data),
    'TotalDisplayRecords'=>count($data),
    'aaData'=>$data
);

echo json_encode($results);
```

Regards,
Elio Fernandes

Comment: Mark, I copied the line code with 'fnServerParams' and in the php file I just tried to echo ($_GET["UserName"]) and I get the error: Invalid Json Response. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

To pass custom parameters in the datatables request you can use [fnServerParams](https://datatables.net/beta/1.9/examples/server_side/custom_vars.html) which you add to the datatables initialisation code, like this:

```
$('#mytable').DataTable({
    "bProcessing": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "go1.php",  
    "fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
        aoData.push({ "name": "UserName", "value": $('[name="iname"]').val() });    
    },          
    "aoColumns": [
                    { mData: 'Name' },
                    { mData: 'Start Date' },
                    { mData: 'End Date' },
                    { mData: 'Notes' }          
                   ]
});
```

Every time the datatable draws, the new parameter will also be passed. On the server-side, you need to get the new custom parameter from the querystring, which in PHP I believe is `$_GET["UserName"]`.

Note that you're using datatables v1.9 syntax, so my example does the same (even though you use the uppercase `Datatables` to initialise).  If you want to use v1.10 then use [ajax.data](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data), the syntax is a bit different.

Comment: Mark, I copied the line code with 'fnServerParams' and in the php file I just tried to echo ($_GET["UserName"]) and I get the error: Invalid Json Response. What am I missing?